# Assigning MySQL rows to Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am using Smarty on a project and I'm finding myself doing far too much in the way of string formatting in my Smarty template, thus defeating the purpose of using Smarty. This is especially true of data from MySQL, often requiring formatting such as `stripslashes` and `replace`.

I would like to do this type of formatting on the PHP side rather than in the Template but I am unsure how to assign the data from MySQL to Smarty and then itierate over it. Here is the PHP that I have been using to assign rows from MySQL to Smarty:

```
while ($entry = $getBlogEntries->fetch()) {
    $entries[] = $entry;
}
```

A simple array with each row fetched, no formatting. It is then assigned with:

```
$smarty->assign('blogEntries', $entries);
```

And finally iterated over like so:

```
{section name=entries loop=$blogEntries}<div class="blogEntry-middle-index">
                    <a class="postTitle" href="/blog/entry/{$blogEntries[entries].id}">{$blogEntries[entries].blogTitle|stripslashes}</a>
                    {$blogEntries[entries].blogBody|stripslashes}
                </div>{/section}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is being able to format the row data in PHP prior to it being assigned to Smarty and then iterate in my Smarty template.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the entries array and call `htmlentites()` over the elements you plan to pass to Smarty. Store them into a new array which Smarty will receive.

```
// Get all the entires on an array like you have done
while ($entry = $getBlogEntries->fetch()) {
  $entries[] = $entry;
}

// New array for Smarty
$smarty_entries = array();

foreach ($entries as $entry)
{
  // Add each element from $entries onto the array for Smarty
  // Calling stripslashes and htmlentites on the fields Smarty will use
  $smarty_entires[] = array(
     "id" => htmlentities(stripslashes($entry['id']),ENT_QUOTES),
     "blogBody" => htmlentities(stripslashes($entry['blogBody']),ENT_QUOTES),
     // Other parts of the entry
  );
}
$smarty->assign('blogEntries', $smarty_entries);

// Now in your smarty template you don't need the stripslashes or escape modifiers
```

Comment: Technically, you don't need to first create the `$entries` array. You can just create the `$smarty_entries` array right away inside the `fetch()` loop in place of `$entries` unless you have a need in your script for the unfiltered original output from your `fetch()` call.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Can easily pass each entry through a function to do even more with it. I don't plan on using Smarty much but when I do, I'd like to keep it kind of what the developer intended.. :)

Comment: I used to use Smarty sparingly but now rely on it heavily. It is quite powerful and well designed IMO

Answer (score 0):

With Smarty 3 you can also create a variable filter to automatically handle escapement of Smarty variables. See this post:

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18926